# Qrcode scanner in xamain.forms windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms, qr-code, zxing

Qrcode scanner in xamain.forms windows phone 8.1, when we use zxing.net.mobile so app is crash at scanning time.

Comment: need more info and rewording in order for you to get some helpful answers

Comment: Provide the code that handles the scanning.

Comment: I recommend acr barcodes.. works perfectly for me..

Comment: Also make sure you have the nuget package for zxing.net.mobile is installed on the PCL and the other platform projects (Android, IOS, Windows) that you will be using.  It has to be installed in each project to work